# Mysql service would not restart anymore

Tags: mysql, linux, debian

My mysql server couldn' t not restart anymore

i was doing the installation of a wordpress plugin, it crashed, then i tried to relaunch the service, I have the error:

```
root@ns3371000:~# /etc/init.d/mysql start
[FAIL] Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
```

This is the log when i launch it in safe mode:

```
mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql.err'.

180822 16:33:07 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
180822 16:33:07 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
180822 16:33:07 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
180822 16:33:07 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
180822 16:33:07 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
180822 16:33:07 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
180822 16:33:07 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
180822 16:33:07 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
180822 16:33:07 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 12059835
180822 16:33:07  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Error: tried to read 65536 bytes at offset 0 2358272.
InnoDB: Was only able to read 1024.
InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot read from file. OS error number 17.
180822 16:33:10  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140608317830944 in file os0file.c line 2549
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
14:33:10 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 346701 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x29)[0x56449ac71dc9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x3d8)[0x56449ab57dc8]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf0a0)[0x7fe1ec9460a0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7fe1eb1d6125]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x180)[0x7fe1eb1d93a0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x67926b)[0x56449ada926b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x63eca0)[0x56449ad6eca0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x66b906)[0x56449ad9b906]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x670eb7)[0x56449ada0eb7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5ce70f)[0x56449acfe70f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x59aa2f)[0x56449accaa2f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x41)[0x56449ab5a151]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x336507)[0x56449aa66507]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0xa73)[0x56449aa69553]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x2bb695)[0x56449a9eb695]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x45b)[0x56449a9ec30b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7fe1eb1c2ead]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x2b2c89)[0x56449a9e2c89]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

I don' t want to loose all my current databases, anything pointing me to sort out the issues would be greatful

Thanks

Comment: I tried adding ## Edit /etc/my.cnf, and add the following line under the         
[mysqld] heading.
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size without success

Answer (score 1):

If the database is broken you can try to access it in a recovery mode.
In your configuration file (my.ini) try to add:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = N
```

where N is from 1 to 6. Then, restart the server.

More information here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

At least, you should be able to access the database in read-only mode to do the dump.

Comment: Hi I tried the above settings with no success, i ended up reinstalling the whole thing, as i havent lost so much up now, thanks anyway for your helps :)